# Self-compiled FFmpeg, checkinstall and APT dependencies

Tags: apt, ffmpeg, libav, checkinstall

I've compiled **FFmpeg** and installed it with **checkinstall**. Now, I'm trying to install OpenCV development files, but it wants to install `libavcodec-dev libavcodec54 libavformat54 libavutil-dev libavutil52` from Ubuntu's repositories, which breaks FFmpeg. I tried using these checkinstall flags

```
--provides='libavcodec54, libavdevice53, libavfilter3, libavformat54, libavresample1, libavutil52, libswscale2, libpostproc52, libavcodec-dev, libavdevice-dev, libavfilter-dev, libavformat-dev, libavresample-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev, libpostproc-dev' --replaces='libavcodec54, libavdevice53, libavfilter3, libavformat54, libavresample1, libavutil52, libswscale2, libpostproc52, libavcodec-dev, libavdevice-dev, libavfilter-dev, libavformat-dev, libavresample-dev, libavutil-dev, libswscale-dev, libpostproc-dev'
```

but it doesn't help. How can I install applications using `apt-get` that depend on libav/FFmpeg libraries? Is it possible without recompiling FFmpeg as static binary?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `checkinstall`, not sure why `--provides` didn't work.

Here another option using `equivs` to create dummy packages for those packages:

1. Install equivs:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install equivs
   ```
2. Generate control file from template:

   ```
   equivs-control libavcodec54
   ```
3. Open `libavcodec54` file for edit. Change name and version if needed:

   ```
   ...
   Package: libavcodec54
   Version: 6:9.18-1dummy0
   ...
   ```
4. Build then install it:

   ```
   equivs-build libavcodec54
   sudo dpkg -i libavcodec54*.deb
   ```

Much work to do same for all required packages, but it can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to recompile FFmpeg and use the local installation shown in this wiki:

Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

This will mean no more entanglements with the Ubuntu package management system...

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is just not what I want. Self-compiled libraries are faster and support more formats, such as experimental HEVC or these with licensing issues.