# Signaling apt I have built from source a newer version of existing package

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, alternative, checkinstall

I have correctly installed from source an updated version of the PointCloud Library (libpcl1.9.1) but I am not able to have links correctly figured out in a 
CMakeLists while building another thing using this library. I need a version >=1.8 but Ubuntu 16.04 [has only 1.7.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpcl).

I would like to uninstall the default version (libpcl1.7) from apt in order to have only the updated one (libpcl1.9) so no issues arise with linking .so libraries. This can't be done because `sudo apt-get remove libpcl1.7` leads to removing other packages I require, which of course depend on *a* version of libpcl but not necessarily on *the* version I'm uninstalling (I also have 1.9 installed, now).

Therefore I would like to somehow let apt know I have an alternative, similar to what update-alternatives would do for an executable, but for a library. I can't use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240932/alternatives-for-shared-libraries-does-that-even-work) procedure as the issue involves other installed apt packages -> multiple symlinks to change at the same time to keep coherency.

The only other thing I have found is [backporting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112157/how-can-i-install-more-recent-versions-of-software-than-what-debian-provides), which seems like a lengthy procedure, and I'm wondering if there is no other (simpler) alternative.

I'm not against keeping the older version, I just need a way for the system to know they are alternatives.

Comment: my question is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/468434/871401 which still didn't really give me an answer

Comment: also related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86176/equivs-enhance-or-update-an-existing-package-without-uninstalling